# Why BlockingQueue is implemented using Array?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Why I think ArrayBlockingQueue implementation doesn't make sense -

1. A queue always adds at the end and removes from the front. Which means a linked list would be the most efficient data-structure to implement it.
2. Queue items are never accessed using index so it defeats the purpose of having an indexed data-structure
3. Arrays are always pre-allocated and difficult structures to increase/decrease in size
4. Arrays require contiguous memory allocation which is not the use case of queues, it might trigger compaction cycle of GC to de-fragment heap
5. Removal of the first element of an array would mean re-ordering rest of the indices, which is the most frequent use case of a Queue. Why to take this overhead ?

Does someone think otherwise ?

Comment: You need to take a closer look at the implementation. It's a ring buffer. No shuffling required.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) states

> This is a classic "bounded buffer", in which a fixed-sized array holds
>   elements inserted by producers and extracted by consumers. **Once
>   created, the capacity cannot be changed.**

All you need is an index to the head and tail.

Comment: That explains the indexing part. What do you think about the choice of the Data-structure. Wouldn't it be more efficient to use a LinkedList instead ?

Comment: @Bhushan Ok, so point 1 and 2 have been dispelled because of the indexing. Point 3 has been dispelled because an `ArrayBlockingQueue` is fixed size. For 4, that will probably very rarely happen in practice. What's more, a `LinkedList` implementation requires more objects to hold the nodes and more variables to reference the next and previous objects. For point 5 again we have the head and tail indices, so there is no re-ordering.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually looked at the implementation, you would see that `ArrayBlockingQueue` uses an array as a ring buffer. This means that while it has a trivial effect on its operations, needing to do simple integer calculations, there's no need to reallocate or reorder anything, ever.